# problem in calculating matrix of an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have 12 matrix 3x3 dimensional,I am suppose to round all of them.as result, I have to have 12 matrix with 3 rows and 3 column .when i ran my code ,i had 12 matrix with 12 rows and 3 column. my code is like that:

```
c=0;
for i=1:12
   for j=1:3
       newmatrix(i,:,j)= (round(G_SUB_A3_N1(i,:,j),8,'decimal'));
       c=c+1;
    end
end
```

Comment: You are mixing up the order of indexing, its row, column, page, see [how to index multidimensional arrays](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html). Swap `i` and `j`.

Comment: `round` is applicable on ND-arrays and default rounding type is `'decimals'` .  So you can use just `newmatrix = round(G_SUB_A3_N1, 8);`